# Error determining module path for sys.argv - every python program returns this error

Tags: python, path, sys

This error started happening after I tried to install plotly.graph_objects and now everytime I run any python program at all this error pops up. I have uninstalled the module now but the errors stays.

Even trying to execute a print statement,
This is the error it shows:

```
E+00000.063: Error determining module path for sys.argv

             Traceback (most recent call last):
               File "c:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 296, in run_module
                 spec = find_spec(options.target)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec
                 parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
             ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly==5'

             Stack where logged:
               File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
                 return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
               File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
                 exec(code, run_globals)
               File "c:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
                 cli.main()
               File "c:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
                 run()
               File "c:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 300, in run_module
                 log.swallow_exception("Error determining module path for sys.argv")
               File "c:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\common\log.py", line 215, in swallow_exception
                 _exception(format_string, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

FOUND THE FIX! if you are using vs code, near the top left underneath 'Edit' there is a dropdown box with a green triangle and written 'Python' select that if it's on 'Python: Module' change it to 'Python: File' this is what fixed it for me. 3 days it took!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more info to the answer of OP. There is a difference between running a file and a module.

The error message seen in the `Debug Console` may look similar to this:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'hello.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'hello' while trying to find 'hello.py').
Try using 'hello' instead of 'hello.py' as the module name.
```

This can be seen in the docs around [configuring a docker container entrypoint](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python#_configuring-the-docker-container-entry-point).

For a module:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "docker-run",
      "label": "docker-run: debug",
      "dependsOn": ["docker-build"],
      "python": {
        "module": "myapp"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

for a file:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "docker-run",
      "label": "docker-run: debug",
      "dependsOn": ["docker-build"],
      "python": {
        #"args": ["-h"],
        "file": "hello.py"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```